# Advice on showing this matrix equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix where the first collumn of $A$ is a $1$ vector
So that $A_{i,1}=1 $for $i = 1,2,\dots,n$.

Define $G$ as a generalised inverse of the matrix $A^T A$, so that

$$A^T A G A^T A = A^T A$$,

Further define $B$ as the $n\times n$ matrix of $1$'s. So that $B_{i,j}=1$ for all $i,j$.

My problem is to show that

$$AGA^TB = B$$

I already proved by properties of $G$ that

$$A G A^T A = A$$

And so, at least to me, I think I need to use this fact combined with the fact the first collumn of $A$ is the $1$ vector to show

$$AGA^T B = B$$

I was wondering if it would be right to partition $A$ as

$$A = [1 \space C]$$

for some matrix $C$. Then, assuming this is a valid use of partitioning (??), this would give

$$AGA^T [1 \space C] = [1 \space C]$$

And hence

$$AGA^T 1 = 1$$

$$A G A^T 11^T = 11^T$$

$$AGA^T B = B$$

But I feel like is not valid. Any advice?

Comment: What is $J$? Is $J=B$?

Comment: Sorry, I accidently changed notation midway through. Corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When computing a general matrix product $Z = XY$, any column of $Z$ depends only on the left factor $X$ and the corresponding column of the right factor $Y$.

Now apply this to the product $AGA^T \cdot  A = A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very simple but clear explanation